# SwingWorker doInBackground() doesn't work

Tags: java, concurrency, joptionpane, swingworker

I am trying to show a progress bar while I do some tasks on a database. The Progress bar, however, freezes and the Things I want to do on the database aren't executed. I understand that, in order to guarantee proper concurrency in Swing I need to do the database tasks on a secondary thread. I also understand that somehow my bug has to do with JOptionPane. But I can't come up with a solution to fix it. Here is the Code for my Progress Dialog:

```
public class ProgressDialog extends JDialog {
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProgressDialog() {

        setModal(true);
        setTitle("Fortschritt");
        setSize(200, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
        pb.setIndeterminate(true);
        pb.setValue(0);
        add(pb);

        setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

And here is the Code where I call this constructor:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(GUIAutoTest.jtable,
    "Schaden mit Testkonfig = " + index + " anlegen ?", "Bestätigen",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    final  ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        InitTestLauf itl;
        try {
            itl = new InitTestLauf(index);
            StartTestLauf stl = new StartTestLauf(itl.getIdTstLauf());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        System.out.println("done");
        pd.setVisible(false);
    }
}.execute();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(GUIAutoTest.jtable,
        "Schaden angelegt. " + "Schadennummer: " + StartTestLauf.getSchadenNr(),
        "Schaden angelegt", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

It doesn't matter, what happens inside the doInBackground()-block , not even System.out.println("print something") does work. Where is my mistake ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way we can help since we have no idea what the code in your custom classes do. So you need to read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars]() for a working example to get you started.

Comment: What is `ProgressDialog`, and why does your `SwingWorker` create one, and then never do anything to it except `pd.setVisible(false)`?

Comment: Also, your `SwingWorker` creates a new `StartTesstLauf` instance, and then it never calls any method on the new object at all.  Did you forget something? or do you call the constructor for its side effects?

Comment: You definitely should not be setting visible in your constructor. You haven't closed the braces on your if statement, this looks heavily paraphrased and you're possibly skipping something.

Comment: @camickr : Sorry i should have provided you with the ProgressDialog class of Course. See my edited question for that

Comment: @matt When I don't set visible in my constructor, how can I make the ProgressDialog(containing the JProgressBar) visible ?

Comment: @Phreneticus did you look at my answer? Can you see the difference? There isn't too much you have to change to get your current situation to conform to what I have provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an example that uses a progress bar with a dialog and a swingworker.

```
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created on 13.06.17.
 */
public class DialogJunker {
    static class ProgressDialog extends JDialog {
        JProgressBar bar;
        ProgressDialog(){
            setModal(true);
            bar = new JProgressBar();
            add(bar);
            pack();
        }
        void setProgress(int i){
            bar.setValue(i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("diddly dialog");
        JButton button = new JButton("start");
        button.addActionListener(evt->{
            ProgressDialog log = new ProgressDialog();

            new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>(){
                @Override
                public Void doInBackground(){
                    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                            publish(i);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                public void done(){
                    log.setVisible(false);
                    log.dispose();
                }
                @Override
                protected void process(List<Integer> ints){
                    log.setProgress(ints.get(0));
                }


            }.execute();

            log.setVisible(true);

        });
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This example will show a dialog with a progress bar that gets updated, then close the dialog when finished.

After reviewing you code a little more, I do see the problem. You are constructing the `ProgressDialog` in the `SwingWorker` class, but you set your progress dialog to visible, *which blocks*. Take note that I have solved quite a few issues.

- I call set visible after starting the swing worker.
- I publish the results so that the dialog actually gets updated.
- I keep a reference to the progress bar, so it actually can be updated.

Comment: Thanks! The main Problem was that I called setVisible at the wrong position and now I understand why this couldn't work. But can I really create a realistic JProgressBar with a Status update shown in % done, when the procedure, which the ProgressBar supervises, is an Oracle (PL/SQL) Procedure ?

Comment: Yes, that pesky modal dialog blocking.

Comment: Do you have anyway to estimate how long the task takes, or does it provide any sort of progress indication?

Comment: Well, basically I do, but it's a little complicated. Let's just say, it can take any amount between 10 and 20 seconds

Comment: Maybe just use a Timer that updates the progress bar somewhat arbitrarily, or use a constantly spinning progress bar to indicate it is working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938040/determining-querys-progress-oracle-pl-sql#15941918