# Oracle (11.2.0.1) : How to identify the row which is currently updated by the UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sql-update

My table contains around 1 Billion Records. My UPDATE statement took more time to update the huge volume of records.

Is there any Oracle view to check how many rows are updated currently?

Comment: They will all be updated at once or none. There is no in-between.

Comment: By design the update is atomic. You probably want to break the update down in multiple statements. If you still want eventual consistency, then use multiple updates inside a transaction.

Comment: did you update every single row? if so, it's often faster to just build a new table using a create table as select than doing an update

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938040/determining-querys-progress-oracle-pl-sql

Comment: Put a trigger, do update, disable trigger. Trigger should write log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query to monitor long-running DML operations and rollback. 
If the update field is not included in the index, then the value of the `used_urec` field from the `v$transaction` view will be very close to the number of rows.
When the update operation is performed, these values increase, if rollback is performed, the values are reduced to zero.

```
V$TRANSACTION lists the active transactions in the system.
    USED_UREC Number of undo records used
    USED_UBLK Number of undo blocks used
select
   substr(s.username,1,28) username,
   substr(s.program,1,25) program,
   s.command,
   t.used_urec,
   t.used_ublk,
   decode(s.command,
     0,'No Command',
     1,'Create Table',
     2,'Insert',
     3,'Select',
     6,'Update',
     7,'Delete',
     9,'Create Index',
     15,'Alter Table',
     21,'Create View',
     23,'Validate Index',
     35,'Alter Database',
     39,'Create Tablespace',
     41,'Drop Tablespace',
     40,'Alter Tablespace',
     53,'Drop User',
     62,'Analyze Table',
     63,'Analyze Index',
     s.command||': Other') command
from 
   v$session     s,
   v$process     p,
   v$transaction t
where s.paddr = p.addr
and s.taddr = t.addr 
order by 1
```

For example 1. If you update a column that is not indexed, then the number of rows 39915830  and USED_UREC 40000562  approximately coincide  .

```
create table test_update(p1,p2,p3,p4 )
  PCTFREE     1
  INITRANS    1
  MAXTRANS    255
  TABLESPACE  arhiv_data
as 
SELECT a.n_p_u, a.id_reg, a.id_vag, a.vrsvop
  FROM a_vag_atr a;

SELECT count(*)
          FROM test_update a
==>
COUNT(*)                                     
-------------------------------------------- 
                                    39915830
```

Session 1

```
update test_update 
set p2=1234567890
==>
39915830 row(s) updated
```

Session 2
start update

```
USERNAME       PROGRAM         COMMAND  USED_UREC   USED_UBLK   COMMAND_1                                             
---------------- ---------------------- ------------------- --------------------
ASUDS          sqlnavigator.exe      6  4181959    62690           Update
```

stop update

```
USERNAME       PROGRAM         COMMAND  USED_UREC   USED_UBLK   COMMAND_1                                             
---------------- ---------------------- ------------------- --------------------
ASUDS          sqlnavigator.exe      6   40000562   601871       Update
```

For example 2. if you update the field indexed then the number of lines * 3 is approximately the USED_UREC. 39915830 *3=~116705429

```
create table test_update(p1,p2,p3,p4 )
  PCTFREE     1
  INITRANS    1
  MAXTRANS    255
  TABLESPACE  arhiv_data
as 
SELECT a.n_p_u, a.id_reg, a.id_vag, a.vrsvop
  FROM a_vag_atr a;

SELECT count(*) FROM test_update a
==>
COUNT(*)                                     
-------------------------------------------- 
                                    39915830 

CREATE INDEX test_ind ON test_update
  (
    p1                              ASC
  )
```

Session 1

```
update test_update 
set p1=12
==>
39915830 row(s) updated
```

Session 2
stop update

```
USERNAME       PROGRAM         COMMAND  USED_UREC   USED_UBLK   COMMAND_1                                             
---------------- ---------------------- ------------------- --------------------
ASUDS          sqlnavigator.exe      6  116705429   1392538        Update
```

For example 3. if you insert into table not indexed then the number of rows is exactly the USED_UREC.

```
create table test_update(p1,p2,p3,p4 )
      PCTFREE     1
      INITRANS    1
      MAXTRANS    255
      TABLESPACE  arhiv_data

 SELECT count(*)
              FROM test_update a
==>
    COUNT(*)                                     
    -------- 
          0
```

Session 1

```
declare
 i pls_integer:=1;
begin
for i in 1..500000 loop
insert into test_update(p1,p2,p3,p4)
values(1,2,3,sysdate); 
end loop;
end;

select count(*) from  test_update
==>
COUNT(*)                                     
----------- 
     500000
```

Session 2

```
USERNAME       PROGRAM         COMMAND  USED_UREC   USED_UBLK   COMMAND_1
```

---

```
    ASUDS          sqlnavigator.exe      2     500000    5815    Insert
```

For example 4. if you delete from table not indexed then the number of rows is exactly the USED_UREC.

Session 1

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM test_update a
    ==>
        COUNT(*)                                     
        -------- 
         500000
delete from  test_update
==>
500000 row(s) deleted
```

Session 2

```
    USERNAME       PROGRAM         COMMAND  USED_UREC   USED_UBLK   COMMAND_1                                             
---------------- ---------------------- ------------------- --------------------
        ASUDS      sqlnavigator.exe   7      500000      9616         Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want to monitor the progress of a long-running `UPDATE` statement? No, I don't know any straightforward way of doing that. No session outside the one running the update statement can see the changes in the table until you commit them.

What you could do is write a PL/SQL program that does it in batches and issues a `COMMIT` statement in between. That way, a different session could watch the table and see it as pieces of it were updated.