# Is there a way to measure or monitor a scheduler job's resources used?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, scheduler, job-scheduling

Recently i got the task to optimize a quite huge PLSQL script which prior to my changes took about 1 hour +/- 10mins.

So I got to do some reallocation of some methods and generally just some replacement of big views with simpler subquery or with statements. I noticed that if I ran the scheduled job by right-clicking it and execute job I would in most cases see the run duration change (in a positive way). But if I enabled the job and let it run by its schedule it takes the original hour no matter what changes you do to it.

Now my question here is: Is there any way to monitor the RAM or CPU usage of the session/job or is there a difference in general how many resources are allocated to background processes? Because my suspicion here is the "manual" run job somehow gets some priorities the scheduler doesn't get or doesn't take.

Either way for troubleshooting purposes you can't take a few hours a work day just to wait for results.

Comment: v$longops is your friend - you can write status updates to it, and then query the progress of your program https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941918/1156452

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith i'm currently just writing in another table when one procedure finishes and starts the other but nothing else gets tracked. I'll try it out soon.

Comment: Does the background job run during work hours? Or perhaps it's contending for resources with other processes running overnight, processes which aren't executing when you run it manually?

Comment: The problem occurs during day and night but i'm unable to see how many resources are used. The schema itself doesnt have many jobs currently but if some were to run at night at the same time my job is running i should be able to see a variation in run time which i don't @APC.